# Angular implementation

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

I just stumbled across [this example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi-v2) for SPA and I am wondering if someone has already done something similar in an Angular app with TypeScript service/component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found something on Github as reference:
https://github.com/sunilbandla/msal-angular-sample